# how to Instantiate the list of abstract parent class

Tags: java

Here is some part of the practice.

[image]

I created an abstract parent class called Equipment, which has four child classes as shown as ConcreteMixer. Then the exercise asked me to create a class named Job, in which its constructor is as shown in the figure. I can’t understand the meaning of the list parameter, but I still created a class according to its requirements, and set it in It is instantiated in the main function.

This is the result of instantiation. I don’t know what the result of this parameter instantiation has to do with Equipment and its subclasses

```
public abstract class Equipment {
        String requirement;
        public Equipment(String requirements){
            this.requirement=requirements;
        }
        public String getRequirement() {
        return requirement;
    }
}

public class ConcreteMixer extends Equipment{

    public ConcreteMixer(String requirement){
        super(requirement);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  requirement;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof ConcreteMixer) {
            ConcreteMixer that = (ConcreteMixer) obj;
            return this.requirement.equals(that.requirement);
        } return false;
    }
}


public Job(Address location, String description,List<Equipment> requiredEquipment, Date plannedDate) {
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;
        this.requiredEquipment = requiredEquipment;
        this.plannedDate = plannedDate;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job s= new Job(new Address("Star street",16, "da","London"),"mixer",new 
        ArrayList<Equipment>(),new Date(12,5,21));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

and this is the result for the main method
location:Address isLondonStar street16da
description:mixer
requiredEquipment:[]
plannedDate:day:12
month:5
year:21

Answer (score 1):

As shown, your image shows nothing about using (or defining) your Equipment subclasses

But the point of the parameter is that the job can use multiple of any Equipment type

```
List<Equipment> e = new ArrayList<>();
e.add(new ConcreteMixer("concrete"));
Job j = new Job(..., e,...);
```

Comment: This is a textual description that indicates any special requirements the
piece of equipment should meet for this particular job. Define the following method:
public Equipment(String requirements)
Post: Initializes the fields with the arguments provided.
Next we need 4 different classes that are going to extend from Equipment;
these classes do not have any additional attributes.
ConcreteMixer
JackHammer
ScaffoldingTower
Torch
Implement a constructor for each of theses classes that takes String
requirements, and passes this value on to the constructor of the parent
(Equipment).

Comment: the problem is that how can I use or create an object multiple of any Equipment type by list<Equipment> in the main method, like new Arraylist<ConcreteMixer>?

Comment: You cannot add a Jackhammer to a list of concrete mixers. You can add it to a list of equipments